# Ignore CSV Column

Tags: php

Hi for some reason my following code isnt working:

```
if (($handle = fopen('https://www.national-lottery.co.uk/player/euromillions/results/downloadResultsCSV.ftl', 'r')) === false) {
    die('Error opening file');
}
$headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ',');
$complete = array();

while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ',', "'")) {
    $complete[] = array_combine($headers, $row);
        ++$row;
}
fclose($handle);
```

I think it's to do with the data in the CSV file (the column Raffle having quotation marks in?) - is there a way I can ignore this column Raffle?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: it does not seem to be retrieving any data (the same code is working for another URL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$headers` is not being properly populated due to there being an empty line at the beginning of the file.  Try the following, which reads multiple lines until it reaches the header:

```
if (($handle = fopen('https://www.national-lottery.co.uk/player/euromillions/results/downloadResultsCSV.ftl', 'r')) === false) {
    die('Error opening file');
}
do {
    $headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1024);
} while (is_array($headers) && count($headers) != 9);
$complete = array();

while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1024)) {
    $complete[] = array_combine($headers, $row);
    ++$row;
}
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Tim, thanks so much - I was finding it hard to explain what was happening because I just didn't know. Thanks for taking the time much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The enclosure of this CSV file is " not '

Answer (score 0):

You define the single quotation mark as enclosure, but the source file has no enclosure:

Based on:

```
$row = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ',', "'")
```

PHP expects your data to be in this format:

```
'07-Jun-2013','14','26','45','50','7','2','7','LSH166797'
```

but the file is in this format:

```
07-Jun-2013,14,26,45,50,7,2,7,LSH166797
```

There might be other problems in your code, I didn't dig too deep.

To avoid hassles, you can just use fgets and explode() each line.